# Problematic caching with rack cache

Tags: ruby, http, caching, rack, rack-cache

I am trying to cache a response from a server locally per example shown [here](https://github.com/crohr/rest-client-components).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'restclient/components'
require 'rack/cache'
RestClient.enable Rack::Cache,
                  :metastore => 'file:/tmp/cache/meta',
                  :entitystore => 'file:/tmp/cache/body',
                  :verbose => true
RestClient.get 'http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/?fg=1'
```

Somehow I always get *miss* as a response and the folder is empty. I guess caching doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
cache: [GET /intl/en/policies/privacy/?fg=1] miss
```

**Update**

The repsponse header contains:

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, private, max-age=0
```

So I guess my question is how to intercept a response before it is processed and modify response header fields?

Comment: Have you looked at the response headers? Perhaps they don't allow caching

Comment: They don't allow caching, but I am looking to override this behavior. I need to be able to force caching at will on the client.

Answer (score 2):

Rack::Cache is "standards-compliant", which in this case means it pays attention to the cache headers. It has [an option for allow_reload](http://rtomayko.github.io/rack-cache/configuration), but that won't help with the specific header you're seeing.

So to use Rack::Cache, you'd need to either intercept the request first, probably by monkeypatching Rack::Cache, or you'd need to fork Rack::Cache to allow the behavior you want. I wouldn't do either of those here.

In this case, I'd recommend not using Rack::Cache, and instead directly writing a very simple cache based on raw RestClient. Check the cache freshness yourself and only send the request if you need to.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing.